# Reset SignalProducer state based on timer and result

Tags: frp, reactive-swift

I have a `SignalProducer` `producer` that asynchronously sends `Int`s. I can sum the values with

```
producer.scan(0, +)
```

Suppose I want to reset the sum to `0` if it is `> 10` and no other values have been sent for 1 second. My first attempt looked like this:

```
producer
  .scan(0, +)
  .flatMap(.latest) { n -> SignalProducer<Int, NoError> in
    if n <= 10 {
        return SignalProducer(value: n)
    } else {
        return SignalProducer.merge([
            SignalProducer(value: n),
            SignalProducer(value: 0).delay(1, on: QueueScheduler.main)
            ])
    }
  }
```

While this correctly sends `0`, it doesn't reset the state in `scan`. That is, a sequence of `9, 8, long pause, 7` sends `9, 17, 0, 24`.

Is there a way to combine these two concept in a way that correctly resets the state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `startWithSignal` to gain access to the produced `Signal` in order to create a reset trigger to merge with the incoming values. I'm using an enum as my value to indicate whether the value coming into the `scan` is a reset trigger or an `Int` to accumulate.

```
enum ValOrReset {
    case val(Int)
    case reset
}


producer.startWithSignal { signal, _ in
    resetTrigger = signal
        .debounce(TimeInterval(1.0), on: QueueScheduler.main)
        .map { _ in .reset }

    signal
        .map { val in .val(val) }
        .merge(with: resetTrigger)
        .scan(0) { (state, next) in
            switch next {
            case .val(let val):
                return state + val
            case .reset:
                if state > 10 {
                    return 0
                }
                else {
                    return state
                }
            }
        }
        .observeValues { val in
            print(val)
        }
}
```

The way `startWithSignal` works is that it ensures no values will come until the closure is finished, which means you can create multiple downstream signals and wire them together without worrying about missing any values, even if the producer sends values synchronously.